# what is added to phtml files?

Tags: zend-framework, utf-8, php

I was using zend framework to build a site. All the .php controller files and all .phtml files were encoded as utf-8(without BOM). When I visited the site on localhost, most of the stuff were shown as I expected. ALL English and Chinese characters were presented correctly. But one problem is that there were two unreadable characters at the bottom of the page(not part of the footer of my html), each of which looks like a black diamond with a '?' inside. I changed the file suffix(.phtml) to .html, and opened it with a browser directly, it seemed ok--no unreadable characters. What seems to be wrong with my phtml files?

Comment: Since we have no `phtml` files, and *you do*, I think you should look at the last few bytes with a HEX editor or a tool like `od(1)` and tell us what they are...

Comment: @pavium : Thanks for your reminding. Here are the last few bytes in the index.phtml file(quotes are used to mark the boundary, no quotes in the original .phtml file): "</div>  </body>  </html>". and the correspondent hex string is :"3C,2F,64,69,76,3E,0D,0A,3C,2F,62,6F,64,79,3E,0D,0A,3C,2F,68,74,6D,6C,3E".

Comment: Nothing strange in these values. There doesn't seem to be anything which would look like you describe -- no black diamonds.

Comment: You can see the black diamonds at the left bottom of the page:[link](http://photo.163.com/zoohuang/big/#aid=224360237&id=7011656600)

Comment: not in my browser (FF3.16). I *can* see all the Chinese characters on the page, though.

Comment: No, actually, I *can* see two black diamonds on the page, but they're in the middle of the page.

Comment: lol. well... I am sorry, I meant the picture in the middle. The picture is a little screenshot of my index page. I put the picture in my photo album. That's the link to that picture. sorry...and I have new findings. I looked at the last few bytes of the source file(downloaded from my browser when I visited my website locally) with a hex editor and I got these : 0D 0A 0D 0A EF BF BD EF BF BD. since everything was right if I open the .phtml directly, can I say those strange characters(utf-8 chars) were from the controller files? Have you ever run into such a problem?

Comment: No, but I've never had to worry about UTF-8 encoding at all because simple ASCII is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a closed php tag in some controller or other non-template php file. Having so may cause some thrash characters to escape to the output. As a rule of thumb, never ever close php tags on non-template php files and/or classes.

**Correct form:**

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    ...
public function indexAction()
{
        ...
}
    ...
}
```

**Incorrect:**

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    ...
public function indexAction()
{
        ...
}
    ...
}
?>
```

Usually time is wasted searching the problem in the template (.phtml) files, when it's not there.

Comment: I modified my .php files as you suggested, but the unreadable characters were still there at the bottom of the whole page. It seems to be caused by utf-8 encoding. When I took away "charset=utf-8" from the meta tag, those two black diamonds with a '?' inside disappeared, and of course, other characters went wrong too. I will try some other solutions. Thanks for your quick reply.^.^

Comment: Hi zoogoo, sorry it didnt work, I had the same problem as you, so I shared my solution :) good luck and lets us know what was the problem when you find it.

Comment: Is it possible to be caused by something like session_start()? One of my page(error.phtml) is running well and there is no session started in the particular controller file. I didn't output anything before every session_start(), so something might be output automatically and invisibly in other pages. But what was it?